# Correlation matrix with p-values for xtable

Tags: r, sweave, correlation

I want to have correlation matrix with p-values for `xtable` to be use in `Sweave`. I tried this

```
library(ltm)
library(xtable)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(1000), 100, 10, dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:10]))
rcor.test(mat)
xtable(rcor.test(mat))
```

and it throws this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xtable") : 
  no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "rcor.test"
```

I wonder how to get the correlation matrix with p-values for `xtable` to be use in `Sweave`. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: On a side note - I would suggest checking out knitr.  It's basically Sweave but *a lot* nicer to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see what's going on I would always suggest saving the object of interest and then looking at its structure using `str`.

```
library(ltm)
library(xtable)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(1000), 100, 10, dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:10]))
out <- rcor.test(mat)
str(out)
```

and it looks like the table that is being printed isn't actually stored in here.  So let's look at the print method for rcor.test

```
getAnywhere(print.rcor.test)
```

We see that that method actually constructs the matrix that gets printed out but doesn't return it.  So to get the matrix so that we can use xtable from this we'll just... steal the code to construct that matrix.  Instead of printing out the matrix and then returning the original object we'll return the constructed matrix.

```
get.rcor.test.matrix <- function (x, digits = max(3, getOption("digits") - 4), ...) 
{
    ### Modified from print.rcor.test
    mat <- x$cor.mat
    mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- x$p.values[, 3]
    mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- sprintf("%6.3f", as.numeric(mat[upper.tri(mat)]))
    mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- sprintf("%6.3f", as.numeric(mat[lower.tri(mat)]))
    ind <- mat[lower.tri(mat)] == paste(" 0.", paste(rep(0, digits), 
        collapse = ""), sep = "")
    mat[lower.tri(mat)][ind] <- "<0.001"
    ind <- mat[lower.tri(mat)] == paste(" 1.", paste(rep(0, digits), 
        collapse = ""), sep = "")
    mat[lower.tri(mat)][ind] <- ">0.999"
    diag(mat) <- " *****"
    cat("\n")

    ## Now for the modifications
    return(mat)

    ## and ignore the rest
    #print(noquote(mat))
    #cat("\nupper diagonal part contains correlation coefficient estimates", 
    #    "\nlower diagonal part contains corresponding p-values\n\n")
    #invisible(x)
}
```

Now let's get our matrix and use xtable on it.

```
ourmatrix <- get.rcor.test.matrix(out)
xtable(ourmatrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use own function like this:

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow = 100, ncol = 10,
              dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:10]))
cor_mat <- function(x, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"),
                    alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater")) {
    stopifnot(is.matrix(x) || is.data.frame(x))
    stopifnot(ncol(x) > 1L)
    if (is.data.frame(x)) x <- data.matrix(x)
    alternative <- match.arg(alternative)
    method <- match.arg(method)
    n <- ncol(x)
    idx <- combn(n, 2L)
    p.vals <- numeric(ncol(idx))
    for (i in seq_along(p.vals)) {
        p.vals[i] <- cor.test(x = x[, idx[1L, i]], y = x[, idx[2L, i]],
                              method = method, alternative = alternative)$p.value
    }
    res <- matrix(NA, ncol = n, nrow = n)
    res[lower.tri(res)] <- p.vals
    return(res)
}
library(xtable)
xtable(cor_mat(mat))
```